# Coded Algorithm for number of ways to cross a room

Tags: java, algorithm

I am presented with a problem where I am given a room of size n, and a number of steps that I can take to get across the room. The room will always be an integer size, and so will the steps. The same step can be taken multiple times. My goal is to find the total number of possible ways to cross the room without going past the size of the room. An example of user input would be

5 9 1 3 5

Where the first integer, 5, is the size of the room, and 9 1 3 5 are the possible steps I can take. The function/algorithm would return something like this

5 //Room size

1 1 1 1 1

1 1 3

1 3 1

3 1 1

5

Conceptually, I am very aware of what is going on, I have made note that the function appears to start with the lowest values and build from there. The problem I am having is getting this from my head, into working code, any tips, pointers, or code snippets would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advanced to any help anyone may be able to offer.

Current Code that I have been working on / with

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ArraySize;

        int[] num = new int[100];
        int temp;
        int i, n, j;
        int roomLength;
        System.out.println("Size of Room: ");
        roomLength = Scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\nTotal numbers that will be entered: ");
        n = Scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\nNumbers:");
        for (i = 0 ; i < n; i++){
            num[i] = Scan.nextInt();
        }
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
                temp = num[i];
                num[i] = num[i+1];
                num[i+1] = temp;
                uniqueCombinations(num, n, roomLength);
            }
        }
    }

    public static int uniqueCombinations(int num[], int n, int rl){
        int i;
        int value = 0;
        int placeHolder;
        for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
            value += num[i];
            placeHolder = i;
            if(value == rl){
                for (i = 0 ; i <= placeHolder; i++){
                    System.out.print(num[i]);
                }
                System.out.println("");
                break;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

example run:

Size of Room: 
10

Total numbers that will be entered: 
5

Numbers:1 2 3 4 5

2134

2314

2341

451

451

541

514

1234

I am not sure how to account for the situations such as 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of ways to add up to a sum S with N numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588429/number-of-ways-to-add-up-to-a-sum-s-with-n-numbers)

Comment: I would recommend reading up on and researching the coin change problem and solutions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem

Comment: looks like a brute force exercise. I suggest you to try to write code that generates all possible combinations. After that, you can add a restriction to bypass all the invalid combinations, so the result will be all the valid combinations.

Comment: How large can the size of your room become? 100? 1000? Larger? How many different step lengths are available? Are we allowed to go back? Let's say the room is 5 long and our steps are 4 and 3, then 4-3+4 would be a possibility if backward movements are OK.

Comment: The room size can in theory be infinite, but will be tested on reasonable numbers, also you can not go back any steps, only forward steps. The steps have to be forward in motion, and = the room length when summed together, if they are smaller than the room when summed or larger than the room when summed it is not an appropriate combination.

Comment: This is indeed another wording for the well-known "coin change" or "change making" problem. You'll find many questions about it on Stack Overflow; it even has its own tag :-)

Comment: Conceptual questions like this are more suited for [Programmers.se].

Comment: So if m would be the number of different step lengths and n the size of the room, would be an algorithm with running time of O(n*m) ok? Which running time would you expect?

Answer (score 1):

at first I thought I found a simple way to solve it using recursivity.

**Quick FALSE PHP function --**

```
<?php
function print_step($size, $steps, $key)
{
    // get the step value
    $nb = $steps[$key];

    while ($size >= $nb)
    {
        $size = $size - $nb;
        echo $nb.' ';
    }
    if ($size > 0 && $key > 0)
    {
        print_step($size, $steps, $key - 1);
    }
}

$room_size = 5;
$steps = array(4, 9, 1, 3, 5, 2);
$total_steps = count($steps);    

// order steps by lowest value (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9)
sort($steps);    

// 1 to size(steps)
for ($i=1; $i <= $total_steps; $i++) {
    // from 9 to 1
    print_step($room_size, $steps, ($total_steps - $i));
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Ouput :

```
5              // starting from 9
5              // starting from 5
4 1            // starting from 4
3 2            // starting from 3
2 2 1          // starting from 2
1 1 1 1 1      // starting from 1
```

And then you can remove duplicates, but with this solution I couldn't get every combinaison (2,1,1,1 for example).

I think you will have to find every combinaisons of every step first, and then look for the possible steps.

**Example of PHP code to find equivalent values --**

```
<?php

function find_eq($size, $steps, $key)
{
    $ret = array();
    $nb = $steps[$key];
    while ($size >= $nb)
    {
        $size = $size - $nb;
        $ret[] = $nb;
    }
    if ($size > 0 && $key > 0)
    {
        $ret = array_merge($ret, find_eq($size, $steps, $key - 1));
    }
    return $ret;
}

$steps = array(4, 9, 1, 3, 5, 2);

// order steps by lowest value (1, 3, 4, 5, 9)
sort($steps);    

$tot_eqs = array();

// From 1 to 9
foreach ($steps as $key => $value) {

    $eqs = array();

    // smallest so no equivalent
    if ($key == 0) continue;    

    //find eq from (key - 1) to 0
    for ($i = ($key - 1); $i >= 0 ; $i--) {
        $eqs[] = find_eq($value, $steps, $i);
    }
    $tot_eqs[$value] = $eqs;
}    

var_dump($tot_eqs);
//then find possibles steps and print all equivalent values for each step
```

Output :

```
array (size=5)

2 =>
    => [1, 1]

3 =>
    => [2, 1]
    => [1, 1, 1]

4 =>
    => [3, 1]
    => [2, 2]
    => [1, 1, 1, 1]

5 => 
    => [4, 1]
    => [3, 2]
    => [2, 2, 1]
    => [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

9 =>
    => [5, 4]
    => [4, 4, 1]
    => [3, 3, 3]
    => [2, 2, 2, 2, 1]
    => [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Hope this could help !